# How can I start SQLiteStudio on Ubuntu?

Tags: tar, sqlite

I've seen the other threads on installing .tar.xy files, but SQLite Studio doesn't come with an installer. From the website - "All files are portable packages (no installer, just download, decompress and run)." I've decompressed using tar xvf <file_name> but now I have a folder that I can't seem to run.

Comment: Yo do not run folders. You run apps or scripts. Look in the dir where you extracted the files.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ unxz sqlitestudio-3.3.3.tar.xz 
$ tar xvf sqlitestudio-3.3.3.tar
$ cd SQLiteStudio/
rinzwind@schijfwereld:/discworld/Downloads/SQLiteStudio$ ls
iconengines   lib        platformthemes  printsupport  sqlitestudiocli
imageformats  platforms  plugins         sqlitestudio  styles
```

so it looks like ...

```
$ ./sqlitestudio
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! The simplest things can be so frustrating haha. So is the original folder just compressed twice?

Comment: Tar on its own is not compressed. Once the tar created, it then can be (usually is) compressed. An additional extension is added. With `tar`, you actually can decompress and unpack in one go: add the `-J` option. I just decompressed with the graphical Fileroller utility (right-click in Files)